# JS probability of 10 people selecting the same number between 1 - 20

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to to javascript so please take it easy :)

I'm trying to figure out the probability of 10 people picking the same random number (1 - 20).

When I run the code it returns the same answer every time. I think something is wrong in the 3rd for loop when comparing numbers. Some help would be much appreciated, I've been stuck on this for 3 days now :(

```
var counter = 0;

//Determine probability (percentage) 
for (var i = 1; i <=100; i++) {

    //Create array with 10 elements and assign each element with random integer (1 - 20)                
    for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        var rndNum = [j];
        rndNum = Math.random();
        rndNum = Math.floor(rndNum * 20) + 1;   
    }   

    //Increment counter if match is found
    for (var p1 = 1; p1 <= 9; p1++) {               
        for (var p2 = p1 + 1; p2 <= 10; p2++) {
            if (rndNum[p1] == rndNum[p2]) {
                counter++;
            }
        }               
    }               
}

document.write("The probability of a match is: " + counter + "%");
```

Comment: `var rndNum = [j];` doesn't do what you think it does, and you override the value with the next assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Your code to make an "array" of random numbers is part of the problem. `rndNum` only has one value (it's an array with only one item in it, and you're overwriting it each time). You need [`array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add values to an array.

You want something more like this:

```
    var rndNum = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        rndNum.push(Math.floor(Math.random()* 20) + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to know the probability that twenty people will pick the same random number?

```
alert("The probability of a match is: " + (Math.pow(.1, 20)*100)+ "%");
```

Or you want to know the probability that any two of twenty people will pick the same number?

```
alert("The probability of a match is: " + (Math.pow(.9, 20)*100)+ "%");
```

Comment: Isn't it simply, `(1/20)^10` ?

Comment: He's apparently trying to get experimental data, not calculate the answer exactly.

Comment: @user113215, isn't it what he's asking? _"10 people picking the same random number (1 - 20)."_

Comment: This math is wrong.  This problem is known as the birthday paradox, see wiki.

Comment: For ten people to each pick the same number between 1-20, chances of being the same are (1/20)^9.  For any two people to pick the same, it's  1-20!/(10!*20^10).

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should also start at 0, not one (the first element in an array is `array[0]`:

```
for (var p1 = 0; p1 <= 8; p1++) {               
        for (var p2 = p1 + 1; p2 <= 9; p2++) {
            if (rndNum[p1] == rndNum[p2]) {
                counter++;
            }
        }               
}
```

You also need to divide your results by 10 because you have 1,000 tests (if you're checking to see if two match). If you want to see if they all match you would need something like:

```
var ordered = rndNum.sort();
if(ordered[0] == ordered[9])
    counter2++;
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EmCuw/1/)'s a fiddle of the combined array declaration and match checkers.